# Averaging scalar fields across an interface

Tags: geometry, average

I have a 1D,2D,3D (line/square/cube) of unit dimension which is separated by an flat interface into two regions. A scalar quantity(p) with a jump discontiuity is defined in this domain.

I know the following :

- value of the scalar field
- the normal to the interface
- gradients in both directions of the normal.

In 1D, its easy! If value at the interface is p* and the grad at the interface is $\frac{dp}{dn}$$|_{+}$ , $\frac{dp}{dn}$$|_{-}$and interface is at x*,

Avg on + is :  0.5(p* + (p* + $\frac{dp}{dn}$$|_{+}$  (1-x*)))

Avg on - is :  0.5(p* + (p* + $\frac{dp}{dn}$$|_{-}$ (x*)))

I am trying to figure out how to do a similar averaging in 2D and 3D.

[image]

Could you suggest a method for 2D extendable to 3D

Comment: Is the gradient supposed to be constant throughout a region?

Comment: Yes... The gradient is assumed constant perpendicular to the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gradient $\vec g$ of function $p$ is constant over a certain region, containing points $\vec x$ and $\vec x_0$, then:
$$
p(\vec x)=p(\vec x_0)+\vec g\cdot(\vec x-\vec x_0),
$$
where $\cdot$ denotes a scalar product.

If the value of $p$ at the interface is known, you can take as $x_0$ 
any point on the interface and then average $p(\vec x)$ over the region $A$ of interest to get the average value $\bar p$:
$$
\bar p={\int_A p(\vec x)\, dV\over\int_A  dV},
$$
where $dV=dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n$ is the $n$-dimensional volume element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Is there a simple way to code this up... Something like a grid imposed on the square and we count the number of points lying ahead and behind the plane... This can easily get us the denominator... Could something similar be done to get the numerator... Like given a point we know the distance from the interface... We know the gradient and the region it is in... Can we just add up the values at Grid points and divide by the total region volume.... Would such a thing suffice

Comment: @Some_guy Of course you can use all the numeric tools which can give an approximation of the integral. Your idea of using a grid should work, provided it is fine enough. The analytical integration is very simple (a first grade polynomial) but the choice of boundary values is not so easy and several different cases should be considered, unless you know in advance how the interface is set.